# Velocity in circular motion, $v = r × \omega$ or $v = \omega × r$?

Tags: reference-frames, vectors, conventions, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I know it might sound silly to ask, but is the relation between linear velocity and angular velocity of an object undergoing circular motion $ v = r × \omega$ or $v = \omega × r$? I didn't notice it at first, but now, I could cite any websites using $ r × \omega$ and many using $\omega ×r$ so I'm just confused which one is correct. Also there is same question asked on other websites but is I guess unanswered or ambiguously answer everywhere. Can someone make clear to me the reason and the correct formula even if it means using right hand rule or stuff like that.

Comment: It depends on the definition of $r$ really.

Comment: Which websites?

Comment: It's not a big deal, because $r \times \omega  = -\omega \times r$, because $\times$ operator is anti-commutative.

Answer (score 9):

If you're seeing web sites disagreeing about something very basic like this, why not just look it up in a reliable source like a textbook? The relation is $v=\omega\times r$. You can verify this using the right-hand rule.

Comment: My book doesn't say anything except $v = Rw$ plus this page on Wikipedia says the same $v = rw$ without any vector consideration.  (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity)

Comment: @Rew Keep reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Particle_in_three_dimensions .

Comment: Hey, gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: @Rew $v=r\omega$ is not wrong. Neither would $v=\omega r$ be. But it is a very different thing than $\vec v=\vec\omega \times \vec r$. The order of terms doesn't matter in scalar multiplication - it *does* matter in cross products.

Answer (score 2):

**Cross product:**

Let's first stablish the rule for the cross product: $ \ \vec{a}=\vec{b}\times\vec{c} \ $ if you rotate from the $\vec{b}$ direction to the $\vec{c}$ direction, the resulting $\vec{a}$ direction of such a product, will point in the direction from which looking down the rotation is positive (anticlockwise), check the *white drawings* [check image].

Or you can also use the typical righ-hand rule check the *orange drawings* [check image]

[image]

---

---

**Question:**

Now the answer will basically, depend on which direction you take the radius to go:

**1) Radius goes from the axis of rotation to the object (mi personal preference, and the most used in the literature I would say)**  $\longrightarrow \vec{v}=\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}\ $

**2) Radius goes from the object to the axis of rotation**  $\longrightarrow \vec{v}=\vec{r} \times \vec{\omega}\ $

As we can see from the examples, of the following image:

[image]

---

---

**Update:**
All the webs and literature I checked use the **1)** (pointing out) direction for the radius, therefore the consensus is:
\begin{equation}
 \vec{v}=\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}\ \ \text{ and } \ \vec{\omega}= \frac{1}{|r|^2} \vec{r} \times \vec{v}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

To be consistent with the vector notation, when $r$ points to the center of mass from the center of rotation it is $$ v = \omega \, r$$ in scalar form and $$ \vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r} $$ in vector form where $\times$ is the vector cross product.